# Using node child-process to inspect prettier requirements

Tags: node.js, child-process, prettier

I have a script in my project that checks some requirements about my `prettier` stuff. 
I am not sure what they are checking, and how I can fix my `prettier` so that it doesn't throw errors.

```
function spawn(command, arguments) {
  const isWindows = process.platform === "win32";
  const result = childProcess.spawnSync(
    isWindows ? command + ".cmd" : command,
    arguments,
    { stdio: "inherit" }
  );
  if (result.error) {
    console.error(result.error);
    process.exit(1);
  }
  if (result.status !== 0) {
    console.error(`Error while checking: ${command} ${arguments.join(" ")}`);
    process.exit(1);
  }
}

function checkPrettier() {
  console.info("Check Prettier ...");
  spawn("prettier", [
    "--config",
    "./prettier.json",
    "--list-different",
    "src/**/*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx,css}",
  ]);
}
```

The prettier checker function returned this in the console `Error while checking: prettier --config ./prettier.json --list-different src/**/*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx,css}`